# Java and C# communication via message queue

Tags: java, c#, message-queue

I have an application in C#, which is extracting some data from files. I want to send this extracted data to Java application via message queue. I have no experience with message queue. I don't want to use web services.

1. Which message broker will be the best one?
2. I have domain models in C# which I need to send to Java app. How to do it? These are just plain POCO classes. Should I serialize them to XML, then to string, the send as a byte array, and in the Java side do the reverse order?

Comment: You can serialize them as XML, JSon or any format you like as long as it is the same for C# and Java.

Comment: Ok, so I have three classes, so there will be three kind of messages. How to distnugish between them? Do I need one queue per one class?

Comment: You could add the type of message to the queue.  When reading a message the parser can look at the type first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) .It's easy to use and also support huge number of developer platform.